# Ex 43 learn python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and have been using Zed Shaw's lp3thw. It's been going smoothly up until exercise 43 in which I keep getting an error message. I think there might be an error in what I typed but I can't figure out where. Please help

I've edited the post to include the entire code.

```
from sys import exit
from random import randint
from textwrap import dedent

class Scene(object):

    def enter(self):
        print("This scene is not yet configured")
        print("Subclass it and implement enter()")
        exit(1)


class Engine(object):

    def __init__(self, scene_map):
        self.scene_map = scene_map

    def play(self):
        current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()
        last_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene('finished')

        while current_scene != last_scene:
            next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
            current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)

        current_scene.enter()

class Death(Scene):

    quips = [
    "You died. You kinda suck at this.",
    "Your Mom would be proud...if she were smarter.",
    "Such a luser.",
    "I have a small puppy that's better at this.",
    "You're worse than your Dad's jokes."
    ]

    def enter(self):
        print(Death.quips[randint(0, len(self.quips)-1)])
        exit(1)


class CentralCorridor(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print(dedent("""
              The Gothons of Planet Percal #25 havve invaded your ship and
              destroyed your entire crew. You are the last surviving
              menber and your last mission is to get the neutron destruct
              bomb from the Weapons Armory, put it in the bridge and blow
              the ship up after getting into an escape pod.

              You're running down the cental corridor to the weapons Armory
              when a Gothon jumps out, red scaly skin, dark grimy
              teeth, and evil clown costume flowing around hi hate
              filled body. He's blocking the door to the Armory and
              about to pull a weapon to blast you.
              """))

        action = input("> ")

        if action == "shoot!":
            print(dedent("""
                     Quick on the draw you yank out your blaster and fire it at the Gothon.
                     His clown costume is flowing and moving around his body, which throws
                     off your aim. Your laser hits his cotume but misses him entirely.
                     This completely ruins his brand new costume his mother
                     bought him, which makes him fly into an insane rage and blast you
                     repeatedly in the face until you are dead. Then he eats you.
                     """))

            return 'death'

        elif action == "dodge!":
            print(dedent("""
                Like a world class boxer you dodge, weave, slip and slide
                right as the Gothon's blaster cranks a laser past your head.
                In the middle of your artful dodge your foot slips and you bang
                your head on the metal wall and pass out. You wake up shortly after only
                to die as Gothon stomps on your head and eats you.
                """))
            return 'death'

        elif action == "tell a joke":
            print(dedent("""
                Lucky for you they made you learn Gothon insults in the academy.
                You tell the one Gothon joke you know: Lbhe zbgure vf fb sng, jura
                fur fvgk nebhaq ur unhr, fur fvgk nebhaq gur ubhfr. The Gothon
                stops, tries not to laugh, then busts out laughing and can't move.
                While he's laughing, you run up and shoot him square in the head
                putting him down, then jump through the Weapon Armory door.
                """))
            return 'laser_weapon_armory'

        else:
            print("DOES NOT COMPUTE!")
            return 'central_corridor'

class LaserWeaponArmory(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print(dedent("""
        You do a dive roll into the Weapon Armory, crouch and scan the room
        for more Gothons that might be hiding. It's dead quit, too quiet.
        You stand up and run to the far side of the room and find the
        neutron bomb in its container. There's a keypad lock on the box
        and you need the code to get the bomb out. If you get the code wrong
        10 times then the lock closes forever and you can't get the bomb.
        The code s 3 digits
        """))

        code = f"{randint(1,9)}{randint(1,9)}{ranint(1,9)}"
        guess = input("[keypad]> ")
        guesses = 0

        while guess != code and guesses < 10:
            print("BZZZZEDDD")
            guesses +=1
            guess = input("[keypad]> ")

        if guess == code:
            print(dedent("""
            Thr container clicks open and the seal breaks, letting gas out.
            You grab the neutron bomb and run as fast as you can to the bridge
            where you must place it in the right spot.
            """))
            return 'the_bridge'

        else:
            print(dedent("""
            The lock buzzes one last time and then you hear a
            sickening melting sound as the mechanism is fused together.
            You decide to sit there, and finally the Gothon blow up the
            ship from their ship and you die.
            """))
            return 'death'

class TheBridge(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print(dedent("""
        You burst onto the Bridge with the netron destruct bomb
        under your arm and surprise 5 Gothons who are trying to
        take control of the ship. Each of them has an even uglier
        clown costume than the last. They haven't pulled their
        weapons out yet, as they see the active bomb under your
        arm and don't want to set it off
        """))

        action = input("> ")

        if action == "throw the bomb":
            print(dedent("""
            In a panic you throw the bomb at the group of Gothons
            and make a leap for the door. Right as you drop it a
            Gothon shoots you right in the back killing you. As
            you die you see another Gothon frantically try to
            disarm the bomb. You die knowing they will probably
            blow up when it goes off.
            """))

            return 'death'

        elif action == "slowly place the bomb":
            print(dedent("""
            You point your blaster at the bomb under your arm and
            the Gothons put their hands up and start to sweat.
            You inch backward to the door, open it, and then
            carefully place the bomb on the floor, pointing your
            blaster at it. You then jump back through the door,
            punch the close button and blast the lock so the
            Gothons can't get out. Now that the bomb is placed
            you run to the escape pod to get off this tin can.
            """))

            return 'escape_pod'

        else:
            print("DOES NOT COMPUTE!")
            return 'the_bridge'

class EscapePod(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print(dedent("""
        You rush through the ship desperately trying to make it to
        the escape pod before the whole ship explodes. It seems
        like hardly any Gothons are on the ship, so your run is
        clear of interference. You get to the chamber with the
        escape pods, and now need to pick one to take. Some of
        them could be damaged but you don't have time to look.
        There's 5 pods, which one do you take?
        """))

        good_pod = randint(1,5)
        guess = input("[pod #]> ")

        if int(guess) != good_pod:
            print(dedent("""
            You jump into pod {guess} and hit the eject button.
            The pod escapes out into the void of space, then
            implodes as the hull ruptures, crushing your body into
            jam jelly.
            """))

            return 'death'

        else:
            print(dedent("""
            You jump into pod {guess} and hit the eject button.
            The pod easily slides out into space heading to the
            planet below. As it flies to the planet, you look
            back and see your ship implode then explode like a
            bright star, taking out the Gothon ship at the same
            time. You won!
            """))

            return 'finished'

class Finished(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print("You won! Good job.")
        return 'finished'

class Map(object):

    scenes = {
    'central_corridor': CentralCorridor(),
    'laser_weapon_armory': LaserWeaponArmory(),
    'the_bridge': TheBridge(),
    'escape_pod': EscapePod(),
    'death': Death(),
    'finished':Finished(),

    }

    def __init__(self, start_scene):
        self.start_scene = start_scene

    def next_scene(self, scene_name):
        val = Map.scenes.get(scene_name)
        return val


    def opening_scene(self):
        return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)

a_map = Map('central corridor')
a_game = Engine(a_map)
a_game.play()
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex43.py", line 251, in <module>
    a_game.play()
  File "ex43.py", line 23, in play
    next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'enter'
```

Comment: It looks like `current_scene` is None at this point. We can't know why with the code you provided here. Please see how to create a [mcve]

Comment: As that reply says, the problem is that either `scene_map.opening_scene()` or  `scene_map.next_scene()` do not return anything. Since you didn't show that code, we can't help you.

Comment: Look at where you're instantiating the `Engine` class or show us a portion of that code.

Comment: Just a guess but try changing `a_map = Map('central corridor')` to `a_map = Map('central_corridor')` to match the key in `Map.scenes`. I.e., `'central_corridor': CentralCorridor(),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake lies in the way you're instantiating the `Map` class.

You're doing `a_map = Map('central corridor')` but that string has no mapping in the Map class variable, called `scenes`.

As such, when you're doing `val = Map.scenes.get(scene_name)` in the `next_scene` method, this will result in `Map.scenes.get('central corridor')`, which it can't find, which will result in the special value `None`. It's just a typo :)

The solution to this is to change this:

`a_map = Map('central corridor')`

to this:

`a_map = Map('central_corridor')`